# Shiny page with global variables crashes

Tags: r, shiny, leaflet, global-variables

I have some large shapefiles that I want to run some intersect analysis on using user input on a leaflet map. My shiny page displays a map that a user can draw a polygon on and I want to see if that polygon intersects either of the two shapefiles. I built a working version of this where the server reads in the shapefiles each time a user connects to the server, but obviously that isn't a great user experience. So I have been trying to move the shapefile reading to global variables that the server loads once, and the user just has to run the intersect on. I'll skip posting my 3 lines of UI for now but this app works locally, it's only when I run it on a dedicated Shiny server that is crashes after the user "closes" the polygon. I have a feeling it's an issue with the global variable declarations, but there is no log file generated so I'm having a really hard time debugging it.

App.R

```
library(shiny)

source("/ui.R")
source("/server.R")

shpfile1 <- st_read("path_to_shpfile1")
shpfile2 <- st_read("path_to_shpfile2")

ui <- ui()
server <- server()

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Server.R

```
# a number of libraries

server <- function(input, output, session) {
    output$s1 <- renderText({"Define project area..."})
    output$s2 <- renderText({"Define project area..."})

    print("Reading New Jersey boundary...")
    mapStates = map("state", "New Jersey", fill = FALSE, plot = FALSE)
    
    output$map <- renderLeaflet({
        leaflet(data = mapStates) %>% addTiles() %>% addPolygons(fillColor = topo.colors(10, alpha=0.8), stroke=FALSE) %>%
        addDrawToolbar(targetGroup = "projectArea", 
                       rectangleOptions = F, 
                       polylineOptions = F, 
                       markerOptions = F, 
                       circleMarkerOptions = F,
                       editOptions = editToolbarOptions(edit = FALSE, remove = TRUE, selectedPathOptions = selectedPathOptions()), 
                       circleOptions = F)
    })
    
    observeEvent(input$drawPoints, {
        proxy %>% clearShapes()
        for (i in seq_along(data)) {
            proxy %>% addPolygons(
                data[[i]][,"lon"],
                data[[i]][,"lat"],
                layerId=i,
                opacity=0.4,
                color = c('red','green')[i]
            )
            Sys.sleep(2)  # - this is to see first (red) polygon
        }
    })
    
    observeEvent(input$map_draw_new_feature, {
        withProgress(message = "Please wait...", value = 0, {
            # capture project area and convert to usable format for intersecting
            feat <- input$map_draw_new_feature
            coords <- unlist(feat$geometry$coordinates)
            coords <- matrix(coords, ncol=2, byrow=TRUE)
            poly <- st_sf(st_sfc(st_polygon(list(coords))), crs = "+proj=longlat +datum=WGS84")
            
            # intersect project area with constraint layers
            incProgress(1/3, detail = "Analyzing shapefile1...")
            i_shp1 <- st_intersects(poly, shpfile1)
            c_shp1 <- sapply(i_shp1, length)
            incProgress(2/3, detail = "Analyzing shapefile2...")
            i_shp2 <- st_intersects(poly, shpfile2)
            c_shp2 <- sapply(i_shp2, length)
            
            if(c_streams > 0) {
                output$s1 <- renderText({"does intersect shapefile 1"})
            } else {
                output$s1 <- renderText({"does not intersect shapefile 1"})
            }
    
            if(c_wetlands > 0) {
                output$s2 <- renderText({"does intersect shapefile 2"})
            } else {
                output$s2 <- renderText({"does not intersect shapefile 2"})
            }
        })
    })

    
}
```

Comment: you can use `preserve_logs true;` in your shiny-server.conf file to save the application logs to see the error messages. https://docs.rstudio.com/shiny-server/#application-error-logs

Comment: @cory thanks, I'll see if I can access that. I work for an engineering firm and they can be pretty picky with permissions :(

Comment: Maybe you can run docker locally to test shiny apps in a server environment.